# Google App Engine configure in a mac

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, installation

This is more like a beginner's question.. So please bear..

I started using the google app launcher - python, I created a new application with port 8080. When I run the default Hello, World application (which i noticed from main.py)

I always keep hitting the 500 error - Internal server.

I find this kind of strange error in the logs:- ImportError: No module named urllib.

I'm stuck.. Can you please help trouble shoot.

Thanks!

P.S: I run a snow leopard with a python 2.6.1 pre-installed, hence I didn't install a new package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this by the following:

1. Installed python 2.7.3 from the python site.
2. Adding the python path /usr/local/bin/python2.7 in the google app launcher preferences.
3. Hitting the return key after typing the path and then closing the preferences.
4. Restarting the application and tadaaa.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this too -- in fact, one of my OS X boxes still has this problem sometimes.  I believe there is probably something in your .profile or site-packages that causes this, but it's difficult to debug.  You could try installing Python 2.7 from python.org and use that.  (Sorry for being so vague.)